# Scikitlearn machine learning pipeline with passthrough parameters

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have implemented 3 `TransformerMixin` classes in an attempt to make my own scikitlearn `Pipeline`. However, I am unable to combine them since `PrepareModel` object uses information from `FeatureEngineering` object. In particular, consider:

```
cleaner = DataCleaner()
df_clean = cleaner.fit_transform(df)
engineering = FeatureEngineering()
df_engineered = engineering.fit_transform(df_clean)
modelprep = PrepareModel(engineering.des_features)
X = modelprep.fit_transform(df_engineered)
```

Note that each of `DataCleaner`, `FeatureEngineering`, `PrepareModel` are child classes of `TransformerMixin`.

How would I make a `Pipeline` with this setup?

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline  
full_pipeline = Pipeline([('cleaner', DataCleaner()), 
                          ('engineering', FeatureEngineering()),
                          ('prepare', PrepareModel())])
```

The issue I have is that the third step needs the `des_features` from the second step? **So this does not work.** How would I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently easy to do; it's probably another use-case for the ["metadata routing" SLEP006](https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep006/proposal.html).

In this example, since you own all the transformers, you might be able to hack something together by just attaching an attribute to the output dataset:

```py
class FeatureEngineering(...):
    ...

    def transform(self, X):
        ...
        return_value.metadata = self.des_features
        return return_value

class PrepareModel(...):
    ...

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.des_features = X.metadata
        ...
```

Comment: I see. So you’re just hacking another column on and then you’ll have to remove later on eh?

Comment: It isn't a column. Just an "attribute" (which you can attach to almost anything in python).

Comment: is return_value a pandas data frame in your example?

Comment: Either that or a numpy array; I haven't tried it (I don't have the rest of your code or data, but also I'm on mobile), does pandas complain about assigning an attribute because it exposes columns with the same syntax? If so, maybe use `setattr`/`getattr` explicitly.